# How to persist an entity with multiple fields of a single type using JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, foreign-keys

**Background:**

I have an abstract class `MobileResource`, which contains three fields each of type `Site`. These fields can, and often do contain the same object.

```
@Entity
public abstract class MobileResource extends Resource implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Site homeSite;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Site currentSite;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Site relocationSite;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

I also have a `Person` concrete subclass of `MobileResource`.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends MobileResource implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String surname;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

The module in question is a **spring-boot** application using **spring-data-jpa** a **postgres** database. The database schema is autogenerated by spring/hibernate.

**Problem:**

I'm trying to persist a new instance of `Person`, retrieved from an external REST resource. When I use a spring-boot injected `PersonRepository` extending `JpaRepository`, and call `personRepository.save(person)`, I get the following exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-07 10:36:30,383 ERROR SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fk_rmnbkmxocx4dcayhiyr1wxypc]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "person" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rmnbkmxocx4dcayhiyr1wxypc"
  Detail: Key (current_site_id)=(738) is not present in table "site".
    ... 62 more
```

**`Person` Columns**:

```
id [PK] | batch_id | brigade_id | call_sign | lat | lon | incident_id | type_id | current_site_id | home_site_id | relocation_site_id | status_id | first_name | surname
```

**`Site` Columns:**

```
id [PK] | batch_id | brigade_id | call_sign | lat | lon | location | type_id
```

**Question:**

What changes should be made in order for the persist to work. My first assumption would be that the schema needs to change, but I'm not sure in which way it would do that, nor how to achieve that using annotations.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I would like to be able to persist the `Site` object when I persist the `Person` object, instead of pre-persisting anything in preparation for the `Person`.

One idea that I had was to use the remote server's primary key (`id`) as a an alternate key and generate my own key using `@GeneratedValue` but I think that might also cause the same issues.

Does anybody know why `CascadeType.PERSIST` doesn't work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no row in Site table where id = 738, so you can't insert that row into Person table.

You should first try to insert a row into Site table with id as 738, and only then try to insert into Person table.

Comment: I'm retrieving the `Person` object via a REST server in an XML format. This XML contains the `Site` objects themselves, along with their relationship to `Person`. In order to use this method I would have to persist every object contained within the object tree of this XML, of which there are many. I was hoping that the persist would be cascaded to the `Site` object?